# Couplers and dividers as baluns

Tags: antenna, transmission-line, microstrip, balun, coupler

Can every divider and coupler that provides 3dB amplitude divison and 180 degrees phase difference be used as balun?

[image: Rat race coupler]

Rat race coupler and lange coupler provide the two conditions mentioned above.

If I place a λ/2 transmission line after a Wilkinson divider, overall structure satisfies the conditions mentioned above.

[image]

My question is, why do we use a different name for these kind of devices if I can already implement them with couplers and dividers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why do we use a different name for these kind of devices if I can already implement them with couplers and dividers?

We often name things for their function, even when we already have a name for their construction.

An "emitter follower" is just another name for a BJT used in a particular way.

A "quarter wave stub" is another name for a transmission line connected in a particular way.

And a "balun" is a transformer or other device used for a particular purpose (to convert between balanced and unbalanced signals).